# How do I post login information to Instagram with Axios?

Tags: python, node.js, axios

I am trying to post a request to Instagram to log into the site via Axios. I am fairly new to Node.js so I may be missing something trivial. I wrote a script in Python that currently works and tried to migrate it to Node but I fail to log in. Here is the code in Python that works:

```py
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

USERNAME = os.environ["USERNAME"]
PASSWORD = os.environ["PASSWORD"]

session = requests.Session()

def login():
    token = getCsrftoken()

    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "x-csrftoken": token,
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "referer": "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/",
        "user-agent": Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
        AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36",
    }

    time = int(datetime.now().timestamp())

    form = {
        "username": USERNAME,
        "enc_password": f"#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{time}:{PASSWORD}",
        "queryParams": {},
        "optIntoOneTap": "false",
    }
    r = session.post(
        "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/", headers=headers, data=form
    )

    authenticated = json.loads(r.text)
    if r.status_code == 200 and authenticated:
        print("logged in")
```

And here is the code in Node.js:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
require('dotenv').config();

async function login() {
    const token = await getCsrftoken()

    const time = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000)

    const response = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "x-csrftoken": token,
            "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
            "referer": "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
            AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36",
        },
        data: {
            username: process.env.USERNAME,
            enc_password: `#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:${time}:${process.env.PASSWORD}`,
            queryParams: {},
            optIntoOneTap: "false",
        }
    })

    console.log(response.data)
}
```

The `getCsrftoken()` function in both version scrapes the site's HTML to get a specific variable.

Running the Node.js code results in the following response:
`{user: false, authenticated: false, status: 'ok'}` which means I am able to access the site just fine but I am unable to log in. I have copied and pasted the .env file to ensure that I am using the same login information in both versions. This leads me to believe that something is wrong with my `data` parameter in the Axios request. I have tried using a `FormData` object as well but that leads me to the same result. Is there anything I need to change in my formatting to make this code work?

Comment: have you tried replacing `data:` with `params:` ?

Comment: @tam.teixeira Yeah I get the same result if I do that.

Answer (score 0):

`axios` uses `application/json` by default (when data is an Object). so you need to change your function to the following one:

```
async function login() {
    const tokenRes = await getCsrfToken();
    if (tokenRes.err)
    {
        throw tokenRes.err;
    }
    else
    {
        //login to Instagram
        const time = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000)

        let params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('enc_password', `#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:${time}:YOUR-PASSWORD`);
        params.append('username', 'YOUR-USERNAME');
        params.append('queryParams', '{}');
        params.append('optIntoOneTap', 'false');
        params.append('stopDeletionNonce', '');
        params.append('trustedDeviceRecords', '');
        const response = await axios.post('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/', params, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'x-csrftoken': tokenRes.token,
                'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'referer': 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/',
                'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36',
            }
        });

        console.log(response.data)
    }
}
```

Please read Instagram terms and conditions before running your code. as I know it is banned by their rules!